# Python Store dynamic data

Tags: python

I don't know if the heading makes sense... but this is what I am trying to do using list

```
>>> x = 5
>>> l = [x]
>>> l
[5]
>>> x = 6
>>> l
[5] # I want l to automatically get updated and wish to see [6]
>>>
```

The same happens with dict, tuple. Is there a python object that can store the dynamic value of variable?

Thanks,

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to see the current value of `x`, why not just look at `x`?

Comment: The assignment operator `=` rebinds names to different objects. You can't make an object for which that doesn't happen when its name is assigned to; it's basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get this to work due to how the assignment operator works in Python. `x = WHATEVER` will always rebind the local name `x` to `WHATEVER`, without modifying what previously `x` was previously bound to.(*)

You can work around this by replacing the integers with a container data type, such as single-element lists:

```
>>> x = [5]
>>> l = [x]
>>> l
[[5]]
>>> x[0] = 6
>>> l
[[6]]
```

but that's really a hack, and I wouldn't recommend it for anything but experimentation.

(*) Rebinding may actually modify previously bound objects when their reference count drops to zero, e.g. it may close files. You shouldn't rely on that, though.

Comment: It's not so much that this is a hack, as that it's just a nested datastructure. You could just as well use a single level of list.

Comment: @Marcin: I just can't imagine the problem for which single-element lists would be the Pythonic solution.

Comment: I agree, but that doesn't take away from the point that two levels of list don't really buy you anything that one level doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is a place to store data. A datastructure is a place to store data. Pick the one which meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `numpy` module.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array(5)
>>> a
array(5)
>>> l = [a]
>>> l
[array(5)]
>>> a.itemset(6)
>>> a
array(6)
>>> l
[array(6)]
```

Generally a 0-D numpy array can be treated as any regular value as shown below:

```
>>> a + 3
9
```

However, if you need to, you can access the underlying object as such:

```
>>> a.item()
6
```

---

Here's a kind of hacky method of dynamic access that isn't very extensible/flexible in its given form, but could be used as a basis for something better.

```
>>> a = 7
>>> class l:
    def a_get(self):
        global a
        return a
    def a_set(self, value):
        global a
        a = value
    a = property(a_get, a_set)


>>> c = l()
>>> c.a
7
>>> a = 4
>>> c.a
4
>>> c.a = 6
>>> a
6
```

Comment: That's not the same thing at all. You could do that with any nested datastructure.

Comment: But most nested data structures do not provide the same "glue" that numpy does for mixing numpy arrays and regular numerical objects. Which is why I used `numpy` specifically instead of regular lists as larsman did.

Comment: Right, but what happens if you do `a = 3`?

Comment: The same thing that happens in any other language that doesn't support overloading `=` when you assign a new item to a variable. However! If you wanted to, you could use the way Python provides attribute access and take advantage of the `property()` function to do something interesting. See my updated answer for a basic/hacky implementation.

Comment: I think that's the closest anyone is going to get to what OP wants.